# how can I alert openfient alert box in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, openfeint

how can I alert openfient alert box in xcode, and error in coming, how can I solve it[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions in that dialog box and your problem will be solved.